# export | grep ROS

Tags: ros, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good evening fellow
This in developing an application with several rivers and probleamas and presented to me in the installation and thanks to your help I have passed, I come to bother with the following error:
income will command terminal: export | grep ROS
Error: does not show me any PATH

Thanks for your time and if you could orienting myself to a solution of this problem is the agradesco, happy night for all

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133756/export-%7C-grep-ros/) by [felipe](https://answers.ros.org/users/11481/felipe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably need to run:

```
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
```

Or add it to your ~/.bashrc

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2014-02-27**:
It also matter where this is added in .bashrc (I've done some trial and error.. but can't quite say yet if I know why it worked and why it didn't)